# DOCTYPE problem, jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll

Scroll.js is used for #bird block, which follows the page scrolling.

The main problem - it is working, if I remove the Doctype line, this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

and **it doesnt work if doctype is on.**

Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div style="position:relative; height:20000px">
    <div id="bird" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:20px;width:200px"></div>     
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And js:

> removed

Dont ask to remove the **doctype,** its **needed.**

Comment: Removing the body after the question's answered doesn't help the next guy....

Comment: Michael - agreed; I've just rolled it back.

Comment: @Mike: reduce the time in setTimeout("b("+m+")",40); to 10 or something to make it fly faster.

Comment: thanks Chetan, will try to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace this:

```
document.body.scrollTop
```

with this:

```
document.documentElement.scrollTop
```

`scrollTop` belongs to the `<html>` element in standards mode, rather than the `<body>` element.

(Note that `document.body.scrollTop` appears three times in your code.)

Comment: I have replaced all the "document.body.scrollTop" by "document.documentElement.scrollTop", and it works, but moves very slowly. How can I fix this?

Comment: is it possible to optimize this script? There is just one block on the page which follows the scrolling - #bird.

Comment: it movers veeery slowly, how to make it faster?

Comment: The code isn't complete - getElementById("baloon") fails because there's no such element.  Plus I have stuff to do this month other than try to understand your code. 8-)  At least your doctype problem is fixed.

Comment: I have fixed the "baloon", it seems to be "bird" instead.

Comment: doctype fixed, by the blocks are flying very very slow, it must be faster at least 10 times - how ti fix that?

Comment: can you answer for my comments?

Comment: I'm sorry, but no, I don't have the time to understand or rewrite your code.  You asked why your doctype was breaking your code, and now you know.  I'm not trying to be rude, but please, stop asking me for further help with this code.

Comment: Woah, you deleted the text of the question!  That's really not how Stack Overflow works - the idea is that the question and answer remain, so that the next person on the net whose scrollTop code doesn't work with a doctype can find the question and the answer.  No wonder someone voted you down - you should roll back the question.

Answer (score 0):

there's one problem on your bird div, the style had width:200", should be width:200px" (add the units)